# Why won't window resize work, except on page load?

Tags: jquery

I need to have a side bar element be sticky when a user scrolls below it, except on mobile where it should scroll like normal.  I am able to get this to work on page load, but if you drag the window size down it doesn't fire the resize() again.  I want this to fire whenever the window size changes.  Any help is greatly appreaciated.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(".jump-to").length) {
      if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        var jumpToTop = $(".jump-to").offset().top - 156;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > jumpToTop) {
            $(".jump-to").addClass("sticky-jump-to");
          }
          else {
            $(".jump-to").removeClass("sticky-jump-to");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add your html? It's likely something to do with one of the conditionals, as adding an alert outside their scope will cause it to continuously set off even after page load (the event listener remains active).

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You set the `scroll`-Event into the `resize-Event` but you have to define it separately. I hope that I got your idea, so the following example may be help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // save elements in variables for better performance
  var $window = $(window),
    $jumpTo = $('#jump-to'),
    jumpToLimit = $jumpTo.offset().top - $jumpTo.height();

  // add triggers like that - not in each other
  $window.on({
    resize: onWindowResize,
    scroll: onScroll
  });

  function onWindowResize() {
    if ($jumpTo.length) {
      if ($window.width() <= 1024) {
        $jumpTo.removeClass('sticky-jump-to');
      } else if ($window.scrollTop() > jumpToLimit) {
        $jumpTo.addClass('sticky-jump-to');
      }

      jumpToLimit = $jumpTo.offset().top - $jumpTo.height();
    }
  }

  function onScroll() {
    if ($jumpTo.length && $window.width() > 1024) {
      if ($window.scrollTop() > jumpToLimit) {
        $jumpTo.addClass('sticky-jump-to');
        return;
      }
    }

    $jumpTo.removeClass('sticky-jump-to');
  }
});
```

```css
.something {
  height: 600px;
  background: #dd8800;
}

#jump-to {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #008800;
}

#jump-to.sticky-jump-to {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="something"></div>
<div id="jump-to"></div>
<div class="something"></div>
```